# What is a round steel bar called with straight grooves running its length called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a variable speed controller that has a knob that's a push fit. The knob is pushed onto what I would describe as being a rod that has grooves like a thread but the grooves run the length of the rod, rather than around it.

What is this type of rod called? And if I were to want to extend it, are there fixtures designed to essentially connect two of those types of round bar together?

Comment: I  would guess it is a bar with a slot along its length. Depends on the function after the extension, you can connect two rods through coupling or welding. Upload a photo then you might get a better answer.

Comment: I think what you're deadening is a *spline* ... search for knob spline...

Comment: Splined shaft it is. Thank you.